# Dell Studio 1749 i5 overheats with Ubuntu

Tags: ati, dell, overheating

I've Dell 1749 with Intel i5 430M, ATI 5000HD and 8GB Ram, so I thought that Ubuntu would work without problems but temperature is about 70-80c when I'm normally using (firefox, thunderbird). **During playing temperature grow up to 95c**!

Kernel 3.5.26, drivers fglrx-updates (required trough Steam). Have you any solution for this?

**ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -15**

> %CPU   PID COMMAND
>    7.1  4405 /usr/bin/dpkg
>
> 6.0  1122 /usr/bin/X :0 -core -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
>
> 4.2  1774 compiz
>
> 3.5 20516 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager
>
> 16.7 22339 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
>
> 1.6 20346 /usr/bin/python3.2 /usr/sbin/aptd
>
> 0.5  1890 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
>
> 0.4  2205 update-notifier
>
> 0.4  1943 /usr/lib/indicator-appmenu/hud-service
>
> 0.3  1811 nautilus -n
>
> 0.2   995 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
>
> 0.2   940 dbus-daemon --system --fork
>
> 0.2 31752 gnome-terminal**strong text**
>
> 0.2  1880 /usr/bin/gtk-window-decorator

Answer (score 0):

mate, I have the exact same laptop and not so long ago someone spilt beer on it, which prompted me to open it up.

after taking it apart using a video tutorial on youtube (alternatively you can use the service manual) I found the CPU cooling fan was clogged very badly. obviously my problem was alot worse than yours (had to replace motherboard and ram) but now I have it running again all cleaned with isopropyl-alcohol (99.9% alcohol) it barely exceeds room temp, when before the same as yours it would literally boil my hands and when playing large games it would turn itself off to protect itself!

so, the service manual is here: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_studio_laptop/studio-1749_Service%20Manual_en-us.pdf

take it apart, or get someone with experience to do so for you if you don't feel comfortable , and clear all the fluff from the heat-sinks and cooling fan.

if that doesn’t help enough (it will help some) buy some good-quality thermal putty (the more you spend the better but mine was about £7/$10) and, still using the service man ( I didn’t at first and regretted it) remove the heat-sinks and clean the old putty off with isopropyl making sure it is really, really clean and apply the new stuff sparsely, you don’t need much and if you use too much if wont be as effective.

I did all this with no electronics or computer tech experience and minimal help from a family member with experience, it's quite a simple procedure if you use the manual.
Hope this helps,
one love